# EF6 inheritance and WPF dataViewSource for collection of abstract class

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, dataview

I have the following model with EF

```
public abstract class Shape
{
   public int  Id { get; set;}
   public string  Name { get; set;}
   public string Color { get; set;}
}

public class Rectangle: Shape
{
   public double Width { get; set;}
   public double Height { get; set;}
}

public class Circle: Shape
{
   public double Radius {get; set;}
}

public class Holder
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   ...
   public int SomeProperty { get;set;}
   ...
   public ObservableCollection<Shape> MyShapes { get; set;}
}

public class Context: DBContext
{  
   ...

   public DBSet<Shape> Shapes { get; set;}
   public DBSet<Holder> Holders { get; set;}
}
```

What is the best way to use it in WPF application and how to set dataviewSource for datagrids?

I want something like:

1. a main datagrid (or listbox or treeView) showing all Holder
2. when an item of the main datagrid is selected a second datagrid shows all the  MyShapes which are Rectangle; a third datagrid shows only Circle of that item.
3. User can add and delete rows on datagrids

For example i have in code-behind

```
circleViewSource.Source =(holderViewSource.View.CurrentItem as Holder).MyShapes
rectangleViewSource.Source =(holderViewSource.View.CurrentItem as Holder).MyShapes
```

and into Resource of xaml I have

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="circleViewSourceViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Circle}, CreateList=True}"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="rectangleViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Rectangle}, CreateList=True}"/>
```

I have problem when for example I wanted add a Rectangle with the second datagrid. The exception is that datagrid try to create the abstract class Shape instead of Rectangle.

I have three table (TPT approach) in database (Shapes, Rectangles, Circles) because I'd like that two shapes has different Id and Name.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the CanUserAddRows into the the datagrid

`CanUserAddRows="False"`

and added two buttons: the first one adds new Rectangle, the second one adds new Circle to the collection of MyShapes of the selected Holder.

Also I removed the part of code.behind related to CurrentItem of `holderViewSource`. Everything can be done in xaml with bindings and DataTemplate.